# Update a row every time its SELECT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I want to update a row everytime it is called upon through SELECT

```
ROW.Hashtag.where{ |hashtag| hashtag.hashtag =~ hashtag_scrubbed}.order{"RANDOM()"}.limit(4)
```

Is there a simple way to do this or will I have to run update later on with those Row ID's selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is using the after_find ActiveRecord callback.

From [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) (slightly paraphrasing):

> An after_find callback is triggered for each object that is found by a
>   finder.

Comment: Is Where considered find in this instance?

Comment: Yes, it's one of the ActiveRecord finder methods: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database

Comment: Does the after_find callback need to be used in the controller or model?  I have this select happening in the controller currently

Comment: I was able to use the after_find successfully.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, and glad I was able to help.